# MouseEvents lagging with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: webgl, mouseevent, delay, requestanimationframe, debouncing

I am running a realtime WebGL animation in the Chrome web browser. I am using requestAnimationFrame, which attempts to trigger frame drawing at the monitor's vsync rate (60Hz). However on some lower power machines (Intel graphics laptops), the webGL rendering cannot run at that framerate - running flat out it manages around 20 fps.

A framerate of 20fps would be fine - except for the fact that in this situation, my mouseEvents seem to be quite seriously delayed / lagging. For example, I print out "mouse" to the console in my mouseEvent handler, and it appears around 0.5 seconds after I tap the laptop's touchpad button. This is a serious delay for a realtime application, and results in my 3D scene lagging behind the mouse movement.

So far, the only way I have found to get around this lag is by using a "debounce" i.e. calling the next RequestAnimationFrame from a timed callback of between 50 - 70 milliseconds. This backing off eliminates the delay in mouse events being processed, but obviously results in a reduced fps. (For example a timer of 70 milliseconds reduces my fps from 20 to 10, which is no good, and a smaller delay does not solve the lagging).

I feel like there must be a better way of managing this per-frame synchronisation. My working theory is that RequestAnimationFrames are being queued up ahead of my mouse events, however I am not sure how to solve this. I know that Chrome passes webGL drawing off to another process, and I have tried to wait for drawing to complete by using gl.finish() - however this seems to have no affect.

Many thanks for any help / advice

Comment: can you draw every other rAF?

Comment: Hi gman, thank you for your reply. Yes, that's certainly a possibility. I suppose that would have the effect of halving the framerate, right? I will try it and see how it behaves.  Is there something that would make that work better that just delaying the next rAF using a timeout (my current solution)?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: Hi ingham. Not really. Rendering every other RequestAnimationFrame wasn't any better than just using a timeout. We also tried using the new "IsInputPEnding" API, to try to ensure events get processed, however it rarely thinks there are any outstanding - yet the lagging continues. I am now wondering if the lag is actually on the GL rendering side, rather than events. Chrome uses a separate process for this, and does not implement any kind of blocking flush / finish command, so it's possible commands will "pile up" on the rendering thread, and lead to a backlog of frames. LMK if you know more!

Comment: Its been a while longer since this post been asked, but did you ever find out more about this? I am currently rendering multiple squares whenever the mouse move and i am also facing this problem. This certainly feel like a pile up problem because I only get these lag spikes when i'm moving the mouse relatively fast or for long durations. Otherwise the lag isn't there. It got better results with pixel manipulation on 2d context and i might go back.

Comment: Hi Martin. We concluded that the lag was due to Chrome rendering webGL entirely asynchronously, which allows frames to get queued, waiting to be rendered. We have started using the fenceSync API (WebGL2 only, but it's fairly ubiquitous these days). It allows us to wait until a given frame's rendering has actually completed - which enables us to prevent the build up, and eliminate the lag. I hope this is useful.